# Maximal number of partial limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I was given the following question in my "Calculus 1" course:

> A given bounded sequence $a_n$ has exactly 2 partial limits, what is the maximal number of partial limits that the sequence: $a_{n+1} - a_n$ can have?

I think that the answer is 3 partial limits: The two limits of $a_n$, and $0$. 
Can you help me with the proof?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If you have only two limits $L,M$ then for $n$ big enough each of the $a_n,a_{n+1}$ are close to $L$ or $M$. What does this means for their difference?